# Z shell does not find script in working directory

Tags: shell, zsh

I don't understand the following behavior:

[image]

This is a Z shell terminal on macOS 12.1.

The working directory is "Config & Scripts".
When I just type `.mouseBatteryCheck.sh` I get `command not found`.
When I add the full path, it's fine.

Doesn't Z shell always look in the working directory?
Does it only look in the directories specified in PATH?

Answer (score 3):

Turn my comment into an answer:

> Does it only look in the directories specified in PATH?

Yes. And you should **not** have `.` in PATH for security reasons. Simply run the script with `./.mouseBatteryCheck.sh` (assuming it has the x bit set with `chmod +x .mouseBatteryCheck.sh`).

Comment: Or put the script in a directory that *is* in your path. `~/bin` is the usual place (though you'll have to add `~/bin` to your path first.)

Comment: @chepner That's a good suggestion but `~/bin` is a bit of a gamble. I'd use `$HOME/bin`, because tilde expansion only works when the tilde is the first unquoted character in a word.

Comment: And in assignments where it is the first character following a `:` (it's special cased precisely to accommodate updating variables like `PATH`).

Comment: @chepner Zounds! I learned something today! Thank, mate.

Comment: @chepner : In zsh, I find it more convenient to use the array `path` instead of the scalar `PATH`. It can be presented in a clearer way, and you can use the tilde without getting in trouble.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't notice this was tagged `zsh`. I would argue the array syntax is easier mainly if you are in the habit of quoting the entire value of `PATH` (`PATH="..."`), rather than just any portion that needs to be quoted.

Answer (score 2):

No, fortunately the shell does not look by default in the working directory. You have to run it explicitly as

```
./.mouseBatteryCheck.sh
```

or as

```
zsh .mouseBatteryCehck.sh
```

If you use the former way, you have to provide a #! line in the script to ensure that it will be executed by zsh.